# How to condition ControlTemplate parameters according to the target control properties in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two `GridSplitter`s, one vertical:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Background="Transparent" Template="{StaticResource GridSplitterTemplate}"/>
```

and one horizontal:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" ResizeDirection="Rows" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Background="Transparent" Template="{StaticResource GridSplitterTemplate}"/>
```

I use this template to give them the desired appearance:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridSplitterTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="5"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,3"/>
            <!-- Or:
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,1"/>
            -->
            </Style>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Grid.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
            <Rectangle Fill="#00FF00FF">
                <!-- Completely transparent, just to fill the space -->
            </Rectangle>
            <!-- Orientation="Horizontal"  if it's horizontal... -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <!--<StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="GridSplitter.ResizeDirection" Value="Rows">

                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>-->
                <Ellipse/>
                <Ellipse/>
                <Ellipse/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

The problem is that this template is valid only for the horizontal `GridSplitter`. I have to duplicate this whole template just to change two fields (the `StackPanel`'s `Orientation` and the `Margin` value in the `<Style TargetType="Ellipse">` tag.

Is there a way to just condition these template values according to the `GridSplitter`'s `ResizeDirection` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it, using `DataTrigger`s:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridSplitterTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type GridSplitter}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,1"/>-->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResizeDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridSplitter}}" Value="Rows">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,1"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResizeDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridSplitter}}" Value="Columns">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,3"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Grid.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="DarkGray"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <Rectangle Fill="#00FF00FF">
            <!-- Completely transparent, just to fill the space -->
        </Rectangle>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResizeDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridSplitter}}" Value="Rows">
                            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ResizeDirection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=GridSplitter}}" Value="Columns">
                            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
            <Ellipse/>
            <Ellipse/>
            <Ellipse/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possible approaches:

1. Use a `IValueConverters` to bind the StackPanel's orientation and margin to the `ResizeDirection` property.
2. Subclass "GridSplitter" and add new dependency properties for orientation and margin.

**Edit** 3. The best one for WPF that I didn't think of -- use a DataTrigger.

The first option seems easier.  Just bind the orientation property to the TemplatedParent -> ResizeDirection, with a converter:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                  Path=ResizeDirection,
                                  Converter={StaticResource ResizeDirectionToOrientationConverter}}">
```

The converter should be something like this:

```
public class ResizeDirectionToOrientationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var resizeDirection = value as ResizeDirection?
        if (resizeDirection.HasValue)
        {
            switch (resizeDirection.Value)
            {
                case GridResizeDirection.Columns:
                    return Orientation.Horizontal;
                case GridResizeDirection.Rows:
                    return Orientation.Vertical;
                case GridResizeDirection.Auto:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();  // todo?
            }
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```